# Solid bordered ellipse with transparent background in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, cs5, fill

This has to be a silly question but I cannot see how, in Photoshop CS5, to draw a red bordered ellipse with a transparent fill over a picture. I often find myself doing this to highlight an area of a screenshot when posting an image to StackOverflow or sending an email to IT support.

In Adobe Fireworks it is pretty easy:

1. Select the ellipse tool
2. Set the fill to transparent
3. Set the pen to red
4. Draw the ellipse

[image: Fireworks screenshot]

It is straightforward following the same steps in Microsoft Paint.

[image: MS Paint screenshot]

But in Adobe Photoshop the ellipse tool seems to only have one colour

[image: Photoshop screenshot]

[image: Photoshop screenshot, toolbar close-up]

I could draw the solid red ellipse and then draw another slightly smaller ellipse to mask out the central region but that seems too long-winded for what must be a commonplace simple task.

What is the speedy lightweight way to call out an area of a picture by plonking a solid bordered ellipse with a transparent fill on it in Photoshop?

Comment: For posters to learn from down votes it is useful if the person down-voting leaves a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the **Ellipse Tool** to draw an ellipse and set the **Fill** to `none` and the **Stroke** to whatever you want.

[image: shot]

### Edit: For versions of Photoshop *older* than Photoshop CS6

Simply set the **Fill Opacity** to 0% and add a stroke **Layer Style**

[image: older]

Comment: Thanks Scott. That's exactly what I'd hoped / expected to find. I've added another Photoshop screenshot to the question that focuses on the menu / toolbar. Mine looks nothing like yours: I do not see stroke and I do not see fill.

Comment: It would be helpful to state what **version** of Photoshop you are using. I've added to my answer for older versions of Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's a useful way of acheiving the effect that I am after, though it is more long-winded than I would expect. I've added "CS5" to the first line of the question. I didn't add it initially as I assumed that this was such a basic and obvious function that it would exist in Photoshop from time immemorial - clearly not!

Comment: It does take more effort in pre-CS6 versions. That's why Adobe wants more $$$ for newer versions with improved features. :)

Comment: This answer uses a Shape or Path instead of the "Pixels" option. Is there any way to have a "Pixels" ellipse without a fill?

Comment: This answer is *almost* helpful until you realize that you have no idea where the Fill Opacity setting is. I had to [seek additional help](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/layer-opacity-blending.html) to find that setting.